# Using Java Read .dat file where data is split up into bytes

Tags: java, byte

I have a .dat file where the information is split up into bytes 64, 32, 8, 8, 8, 8 respectively.

I know how to read a file that has a know split such as ":" but not a file split based on byte size.

How would i go about doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `ObjectInputStream#read(byte[] b)` where `byte[] b` is an array that has been initialised as follows: `byte[] b = new byte[i]` where `i` is the number of bytes you wish to read. Do this for each section changing i/b respectively until you have all of your data.